# Как объединить root и обычное приложение?

Tags: android

Я создал приложение но оно требует root, скажите пожалуйста как можно объъединить root в мое приложение.

Есть телефон у которого нет рута, как сделать так чтобы мое приложение вначале установила apk superSU superUser а после мое приложение, будет ли работать в таком случае root?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нельзя. И, на самом деле, не стоит. И вот почему:

1. Рут – серьёзная модификация системы, иногда есть больше одного способа её применить. SuperSU и Superuser всего лишь управляют уже включенным другими средствами рутом, они ни при чём.
2. Как правило, рут делается при участии ПК, обратное – скорее исключение.
   Скажем, в моём Asus TF101 была дыра в системе, которая позволяла сделать рут "прямо на борту", и было приложение именно под эту модель, которое этим занимается. А я поначалу отчаялся, потому что у моего аппарата вышел из строя порт подключения к компу.
3. Рут может привести к потере гарантии, легко. Для многих приложений такой "побочный эффект" настолько нежелателен, что не стоит установки этого приложения.

Answer (score 0):

`Root` устанавливается по разному на всех смартфонах, и это бывает не всегда. Простое занятие, так что думаю нет.

Comment: Но я заметил что в большинстве случаев это superSU или sueprUser и я знаю что в андроид свыше 5 тысяч моделей, Я не прошу идеальный способ, хотя бы 70% вариант. А утех у кого не работает пусть через комп пробуют

Comment: Ну это лишь приложение для установки доступа\запрета к root конкретному приложению. Сам root получается в следствии, например, прошивки телефона.

Answer (score 0):

нет, не будет. Чтобы установить рут, мало установить приложение SuperSU. Для установки рута почти всегда требуется разблокировка загрузчика, иногда установка кастомного ядра, иногда - применить определенный хак через ADB. Короче сказать - просто через приложение установить рут в абсолютном большинстве случаев не получится

Comment: А если файл su добавить в xbin ?

Comment: чтобы добавить что-то в xbin нужны права на звпись в xbin.

Comment: В таком случае скажите как проверить root есть или нет. Скачал RootTools. RootTools.isRootAvailable() результата никакого нет.

Comment: @xTIGRx https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android+check++root+programmatically