# Диалоговое окно для удаления приложения

Tags: android

Как при попытке удаления приложения выводить диалог с запросом пароля?
 
Если пароль верный - разрешить удаление, а если нет - запретить.

Comment: Вашего приложения? Или чужого?

Comment: Моего, необходим запрет на его удаление без пароля

Comment: Честным способом сомневаюсь что возможно, но можно через администраторов устройства/рут доступ. И вообще было бы такое легко сделать уже столько бы локеров развелось.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Самые высокие привилегии, какие только можно дать приложению в Android, это [права администрирования](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) (и это можно сделать только с разрешения пользователя), наличие их у приложения не будет давать удалить его с устройства.

Но эти **привилегии пользователь может отозвать** без участия приложения, поэтому запросить пароль **по инициативе приложения** не представляется возможным, это намеренно заложено в ОС.

---

Конечно, ситуация несколько меняется, когда есть возможность использовать **root-права** на устройстве: в этом случае приложение можно перенести в `/system`, туда же, где находятся **системные приложения**, способные пережить даже *полный сброс настроек*. Но даже тогда удаление будет всего лишь *затруднено*, его нельзя будет стереть только из приложения **"Настройки"**.

Средство, способное использовать права суперпользователя, сможет уничтожить любое приложение даже из `/system`. В том числе поэтому root-права так часто приводят к лишению гарантии: это позволяет удалить даже приложения от производителя.

---

<sub>[Другой вопрос по теме](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7540037/2076787)</sub>

Comment: А можно сделать приложение, которое будет давать рут права с разрешения пользователя ?

Comment: @researcher есть приложения для управления рут-правами, когда в самой системе они уже получены. В них обычно есть опциональная парольная защита, да.

Comment: А нельзя написать такое приложение, чтобы установив его на новый телефон пользователь мог сделать его рутованым ? П.С. я не в курсе как делать рут права на телефоне.

Comment: @researcher заметно :) Почитайте: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/437468/181100

Comment: Спасибо, гляну) Я не задавлся поиском решения этой ситуации. Увидел вопрос по теме, решил спросить у Вас заодно..

Comment: Приводили в качестве примера App Locker, который работает без рута

Comment: @Igor кто приводил? Ссылочку.